# Python: Black doesn't wrap long lines

Tags: python, word-wrap, python-black

I am using `black==20.8b1`.

I have a long string like:

```
return f"{self.name}, a {adjective.to_name()} {kin_string}{self._type.to_name()} who works for the {target.get_relationship_target_string()}."
```

I run:

```
$ black -l 80 . -t py38
All done! ✨  ✨
2 files left unchanged.
```

Why is the string not wrapped? I thought that `black` supports wrapping strings now (based on issues in github).

Answer (score 32):

Use `--preview` option to trigger this behaviour.

Previously we had to add `--experimental-string-processing` option.
This option still works but issues a depreciation warning.

I think in [future versions it will be made default](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/1802).

```
black -l 80 --preview file.py
```

Comment: Looks like we have a new flag to replace `--experimental-string-processing now`: `--preview`.  When running with `--experimental-string-processing`: `<string>:12: Deprecated: `experimental string processing` has been included in `preview` and deprecated. Use `preview` instead.`

Answer (score 19):

Since [22.1.0](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/change_log.html) (Jan 29, 2022), you have to run Black with `--preview`.

Comment: Thank you! This works for me when I do `black --preview file.py`. How can this work in VScode? I have included `"python.formatting.blackArgs": [ "--preview" ]` in my project's settings.json, but line wrapping is not enforced.

Comment: @KLaz not really sure. These are my settings in VSCode: `"python.formatting.provider": "black", "python.formatting.blackArgs": ["--preview"]` (on MacOS). Looks like we have the same. It works for me. Does your VSCode succeed to format a file in Python (I mean, other than the line wrapping)? Maybe it can't find the Black binary on your system.

Answer (score 14):

Currently, Black doesn't wrap long strings or long comments. You can see an [open issue in their project GitHub](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/1331) saying:

> Black currently doesn't wrap long string literals or merge string literals that happen to be on the same line. [...] It would require modifying the AST which isn't 100% safe and has a bunch of edge cases to be dealt with.

Comment: Do you know why this issue is closed https://github.com/psf/black/issues/182 I thought it was already done?