# Python Black code formatter doesn't format docstring line length?

Tags: python, docstring, python-black

I am running the Black code formatter against a Python script however it doesn't reformat the line length for docstrings. For example, given the following code:

```py
def my_func():
    """
    This is a really long docstring. This is a really long docstring. This is a really long docstring. This is a really long docstring. This is a really long docstring. This is a really long docstring.
    """
    return
```

When running Black against this script, the line length does not change. How can I ensure docstrings get formatted when running Black?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64748098/11246056

Answer (score 40, accepted):

maintainer here! :wave:

The short answer is **no you cannot configure Black to fix line length issues in docstrings currently.**

It's not likely Black will split or merge lines in docstrings as it would be far too risky, structured data can and does exist in docstrings. While I would hope the added newlines wouldn't break the consumers it's still a valid concern.

There's currently an open issue asking for this (although it also wants the line length limit for docstrings and strings to be 79) [GH-2289](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/2289), and specifically for docstrings [GH-2865](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/2865). You can also read [GH-1713](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/1713) which is about splitting comments (and likewise has mixed feelings from maintainers).

For the time being, perhaps you can look into https://github.com/PyCQA/docformatter which does seem to wrap docstrings (see the `--wrap-descriptions` and `--wrap-summaries` options)

---

<sup>P.S. if you're curious whether we'll add a flag to split docstrings or comments, it's once again unlikely since we seek to minimize formatting configurability. Especially as the pre-existing flags only disable certain elements of Black's style (barring --line-length which exists as there's no real consensus what it should be). Feel free to state your arguments in the linked issues tho!</sup>